# how to refresh JWT

Tags: python, flask, jwt, token

I'm a beginer at flask and I wanna secure my app with JWT. I use pyjwt python library. Is it possible to refresh jwt in pyjwt? Lots of information about flask-jwt-extended but nothing about pyjwt.

Comment: This book might help [Link to book](https://b-ok.africa/dl/3658054/50e9cc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PyJWT is a Python library which allows you to encode and decode JSON Web Tokens

This library is not ready for user sessions. You should implement refreshing logic by yourself:

```py
import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

payload = {"username": "john", "session_id": "abc"}

# add token expiration time (5 seconds):
payload["exp"] = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=5)

# this token is valid for 5 seconds
token = jwt.encode(payload, "some_secret_phrase", algorithm="HS256")

# get token data:
decoded_payload = jwt.decode(token, "some_secret_phrase", algorithms=["HS256"])

# if we run ↑this↑ after 5 seconds jwt.exceptions.ExpiredSignatureError: Signature has expired will be raised
# in other case we will get decoded data:
# {'username': 'john', 'session_id': 'abc', 'exp': 1650187206}

# now we should update 'exp' for 5 seconds again
decoded_payload['exp'] = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc) + timedelta(seconds=5)

# and generate new token
new_token = jwt.encode(payload, "some_secret_phrase", algorithm="HS256")

# after receiving this new token client will be able to use it for 5 seconds before another refreshing process
```

My example is super simple, **insecure** and **just demonstrate how token may be refreshed**. You have to use more complicated logic and [refresh tokens](https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/) for real web applications.

Answer (score 0):

I'm beginner also.

The client can parse expire time of access token.
If access token is expired then you have to request new access token with refresh token according to your algorithm.

This is a simple reference source.

https://github.com/nevertheless-good/fastapi-jwt-auth-server.git

Good luck.